# Makefile built-in rules: No rule to make target

Tags: c, makefile, compiler-errors, compilation, cross-compiling

I created a C project that contains following files:

```
mainfile.c
ethernetThreadPool.h
ethernetThreadPool.c
Makefile
```

mainfile.c contains the main function and uses ethernetThreadPool API (ethernetThreadPool.c and ethernetThreadPool.h). 
mainfile.c and ethernetThreadPool.c uses libpcap libuci libpthread libraries. The Makefile is the following:

```
CPPFLAGS=$(CPPOPTIONS) -mips32 -DPATCH_MD -DPATCH_HOSTAP -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__MIPS__ -D__BUSYBOX__ -D_LIBC 
CC = mips-linux-gcc


LDFLAGS += -lpcap -luci -lpthread

mainfile: mainfile.o ethernetThreadPool.o $(LDFLAGS)
mainfile.o: ethernetThreadPool.h
ethernetThreadPool.o: ethernetThreadPool.h

clean:
    rm -f *.o mainfile
```

If I try to compile this project I get the following error:

```
make[3]: *** No rule to make target `-L/path_to_lib_folder/lib', needed by `mainfile'.  Stop.
```

Has someone an idea what's wrong in my Makefile?

Comment: We can use it. I saw it and I tried it in other examples

Comment: Did you try to remove `$(LDFLAGS)` on the `mainfile:` line? That's what the error says. It makes no sense that flags are dependancies.

Comment: but mainfile uses those libraries

Comment: You need to write it into the compile command, not in the dependancy list.

Comment: @mch: thank you your proposition fixed the bug :)